# jQuery data and objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-data

I'm trying to write code something like this:

```
$('[id^=myitem_]').data(
    'powq',
     $([
         '<p><b>Description:</b></br>'+$(this).find("input[name=description]").val()+'</p>',
         '<p>Some other data:</p>'
     ].join(''))
);
```

As you can see inside 'value' i want to catch object inside `[id^=myitem_]`, but i cannot. In this case every time i get first object in whole document. I think here, inside 'value', `$(this)` mean window or whole document.

Any idea..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What `this` refers to depends on the context where you executed that code. It's likely that it refers to `window` though.

If you want it to refer to each `[id^=myitem_]` element, then you have to use [`.each` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over all selected elements:

```
$('[id^=myitem_]').each(function() {

    $(this).data(
        'powq',
         $([
             '<p><b>Description:</b></br>'+$(this).find("input[name=description]").val()+'</p>',
             '<p>Some other data:</p>'
         ].join(''))
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To access div elements with the ID `myitem`:

```
$("#myitem")
```

I might have completely misunderstood your question though.